# how to use jq to print JSON array elements separated by tabs "\t"

Tags: json, unix, command-line, jq, text-processing

I am trying to import a json document to a sqlite3 database using the `.import` function. from what I can tell, sqlite3 .import expect the JSON data to be one line per row, with number of items matching the table column, and separated by `.separate`.

if I define `.separator="\t"`, I am trying to create a reformatted json file using jq, but got an error.

here is my test

```
$echo '[{"a1":{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}},{"a2":{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":"test","c2":null}}}]' | jq -c '.[] | to_entries'

[{"key":"a1","value":{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}}]
[{"key":"a2","value":{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":null}}}]
```

my goal is to create the following tab-separated lines (\t below means tab `\x09`)

```
"a1"\t{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}
"a2"\t{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":null}}
```

but I failed to achieve this format with jq alone.
I could get this separated by new-lines

```
$echo '[{"a1":{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}},{"a2":{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":"test","c2":null}}}]' | jq -c '.[] | to_entries |.[] | [.key, .value] | .[]'
"a1"
{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}
"a2"
{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":null}}
```

but if I use join("\t"), it complains that it can not join a string with an object

```
echo '[{"a1":{"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}},{"a2":{"b2":1,"c":{"c2":"test","c2":null}}}]' | jq -c '.[] | to_entries | .[] | [.key, .value] | join("\t")'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): string ("a1\t") and object ({"b1":1,"c1...) cannot be added
```

I could use perl or sed to postprocess the new-line separated text to get what I wanted, but I hope to learn how to do this properly with `jq`.

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your desired output, use `@json` to [JSON-encode](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#format-strings-and-escaping) any input as strings. Then, use the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) flag to print the string values as is.

The simplest way would be to use [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation):

```bash
… | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | @json "\(.key)\t\(.value)"'
```

But you can also use `join("\t")` from your attempt on a prepared array. In this case, using the `tojson` converter is also possible:

```bash
… | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | [.key, .value | @json] | join("\t")'
# or
… | jq -r '.[] | to_entries[] | [.key, .value | tojson] | join("\t")'
```

Output:

```json
"a1"    {"b1":1,"c1":{"c1":"test","c2":null}}
"a2"    {"b2":1,"c":{"c2":null}}
```

Comment: beautiful! it works! thank you. one follow up question - what should I do if I want to remove the double quotes of the first column `("a1"/"a2")`?

Comment: Have a look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77895746/revisions) of my post. The [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77895746/1) accidentally answered exactly that. :)

Comment: works like a charm! thank you again. I am always impressed by how mighty jq is!